# IIS Rewrite not working (but redirection does)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I was trying to play with URL re-writing using the *Rewrite Module 2.0* but I had no luck getting it to work. What I'm trying to do is re-write all calls to web app at port 80 to other applications hosted in IIS (or maybe on different servers on the network). Using the GUI provided by IIS I created the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="site1/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:7001/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Quiet simple, but unfortunately it does not work. On the other hand, when I change the action type to `Redirect`, it works fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you define "does not work"? I mean, what actually happens?

Comment: Are you using [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module)? As a test, what if you change `type="Rewrite"` to `type="Redirect"`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly yes I am using the Application Request Routing. And when I change it to `Redirect` it does work and redirect me to the target url. But when using `Rewrite` I get a 404 error.

Comment: And you have enabled the proxy mode on the Application Request Routing?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: Yes, of course I did.

Comment: That is really weird. Is it the real rule or have you changed some parts to post it here?

Comment: @cheesemacfly nope, that is the real rule.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 63):

I ran into this same issue yesterday, and it took me a long time to figure out.

The key here is that you've got an `http://` prefix in your rewrite action; that makes this a special case that needs to be handled by Application Request Routing.  The first step is to make sure that the Application Request Routing module is installed.  You can find the module at https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing.  Once that is installed, go to your IIS web server (a level up from your web site), and open the Application Request Routing Cache feature.  From the actions on the right, choose `Server.Proxy.Settings`, and make sure that the "Enable Proxy" checkbox is checked.  This allows the URL rewrite task to be re-routed to Application Request Routing, and your reverse proxy should work for external requests.

The idea came from this excellent blog post from 2009: http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: this is the problem I had. It fixed my issue when I use url rewrite to rewrite to other domain

Comment: this solution also solved my problem. I am rewriting to a different domain name altogether.

Comment: You made my day (after I lost a full yesterday on that problem)!

Comment: This solved our 4hour investigation!

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this old post when I was trying to solve the same issue.

SOLVED!

Using Rewrite URL feature in IIS Services Manager I created a friendly URL rule.

This worked ok and when I looked at the rule in the web.config file (www root) it showed 1 rule to redirect and 1 rule to rewrite.

I edited this to suit 1 match.  Then I just duplicated this code editing the product ID for each. Example below:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^product\.php$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^id_product=\b35\b" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="990mm-bohemia-cast-iron-electric-radiator" 
            appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

The first rule looks for the string `"product.php"` in the URL and `"id_product=35"`, it then redirects to `"990mm-bohemia-cast-iron-electric-radiator"` which currently does not exist. Then (see below)

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^\b990mm-bohemia-cast-iron-electric-radiator\b" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="product.php?id_product=35" />
</rule>
```

This rule rewrites the `"product.php?id_product=35"` bit to `990mm-bohemia-cast-iron-electric-radiator", creating the new location for the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Do make sure MVC routing doesn't steal your request. To prevent that from happening, ignore the route you're trying to rewrite:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("blog/{*pathInfo}");
```

Inspired by: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3645/how-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-with-sitecore

Answer (score -1):

Change the Rewrite URL to AbsolutePath instead putting http://...
it should be

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
```

It worked for me, but in my case, I have been rewrite to a fixed webpage.

Comment: it should be what?