# IIS rewrite to local apps - fails with 404

Tags: iis, iis-8

I want to use IIS8 to route traffic from ports 80/443 to two applications running on the same server - one sitting on port 8080 (node.js app, running as a separate service), another on port 8090 (a .NET application, running on the same IIS, handling api calls).

I have setup an app on port 80, with the following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
              <rules>
                <rule name="rewrite api to backend calls" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api/(.+)$"/>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/{R:1}"/>
                 </rule>
                <rule name="rewrite everything else to frontend" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:8090/{R:1}"/>
                </rule>             
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately this approach doesn't work - whatever resource I try to query, I get 404 error.

In the FREB logs, requests are properly translated from OldUrl, to the NewUrl, nothing is found in cache and then the following is mentioned in logs as `MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS`

```
ModuleName="IIS Web Core", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="404", HttpReason="Not Found", HttpSubStatus="4", ErrorCode="The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 (0x8007007b)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy in Application Request Routing had to be enabled as per the [IIS Rewrite not working (but redirection does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357674/iis-rewrite-not-working-but-redirection-does) topic. Issue solved :)