# IIS Rewrite not working but redirection does

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to get URL re-writing working on a IIS 8.5 server.
I am having the same issue as described in 
[this similiar post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357674/iis-rewrite-not-working-but-redirection-does) that is a redirect works but rewrite does not.

The simple rule for testing purposes is:

```
            <rule name="ReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.10.101.22:52797/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

My goal is to rewrite URLs with only specific path to another internal server.

If I change the rule to redirect it works. 
On a similarly configured IIS 8.5 server the rewrite rule works.

AAR is installed and Enable proxy is checked.
After installing AAR I had to restart IIS for the AAR icon to appear.
I could not see anything in Failed Request Tracing that explains why this is happening.
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you can change the host to another server with a rewrite? A redirect sends a response back to the client and causes it to reconnect -- a rewrite is supposed to continue processing in the same server -- it affects routing in further processing.

Comment: To clear by not working I mean when the rule using rewrite,  the rule is completely ignored.  No rewrite or redirect occurs as if the rule was disabled.

Comment: If I change the rule to redirect, the site is redirected to http://10.10.101.22:52797/

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think this rewrite rule is not allowed (and therefore ignored).  Do you have any documentation that shows that a non-redirected rewrite to another host is ok?  A redirect works because the client makes a new request to the other host.  This could only work if the server would make that request -- I don't know if that's ok

Comment: On a similarly configured IIS 8.5 server the rewrite rule works.

Comment: Is that IP/port reachable from that server?

Comment: Yes 10.10.101.22 is accessible. As I said rewrite works in one environment  but not the other. Something I am missing no doubt but what...

Comment: Different environments can have different accessibility to an IP -- did you check from that server?

Comment: Run wireshark on that server while it's supposedly redirecting and see if it makes network requests to 10.10.101.22 and what happens to them (do they succeed)

Comment: I redeployed the mvc web application (and web.config) and re-added the rule on the server where the rewrite rule did not work and now it works. Not sure what the cause was.